# In Watir, how to get the full text, from a portion of text?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I have a portion of HTML that looks similar to:

```
<table><tbody><tr>
<td><div> Text Goes Here </div></td>
<td> ... rest of table
```

There are no IDs, no Titles, no descriptors of any kind to easily identify the div that contains the text.

When an error occurs on the page, the error is inserted into the location where "Text Goes Here" is at (no text is present unless an error occurs).  Each error contains the word "valid".
Examples: "The form must contain a valid name" or "Invalid date range selected"

I currently have the Watir code looking like this:

```
if browser.frame(:index => 0).text.includes? "valid"
  msg = # need to get full text of message
  return msg
else
  return true
end
```

Is there any way to get the full text in a situation like this? 
Basically: return the full text of the element that contains the text "valid" ?

Using: Watir 2.0.4 , Webdriver 0.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
return browser.div(:text => /valid/).text
```

or

```
return browser.table.div(:text => /valid/).text
```

if the valid is not found, it should return nil.

Comment: You have to be careful about doing this. The text locator checks against an element's text, which includes the text of its children elements. For example, if there is a div tag around your table, the first solution will give you all text in the table rather than just the specific div in the table.

Comment: You are correct, sir. That's the problem with tiny snippets of html-under-test. One cannot create a safe solution for the big picture with such a small view.

Answer (score 2):

Given the structure you provided, since divs are so often used I would be inclined to look for the table cell using a regular expression as Dave shows in his answer.  Unless you have a lot of nested tables, it is more likely to return just the text you want.

Also if 'valid' may appear elsewhere then you might want to provide a slightly larger sample of the text to look for

.   browser(:cell => /valid/).text